# Visual Studio F5 results in a connection screen?

Tags: visual-studio

When I start debugging in Visual Studio 2018  using F5 and a startup-project all of a sudden a database connection screen pops up. Why and how do I get rid of this behaviour? I can start debugging using the context menu  debug-start new instance. It has to do with a legacy, unused database project. When I unload this project the problem is gone.
[image]

In the output build window: "Project: My.Database, Configuration: Debug Any CPU. Failed to debug this project because no SQL Server has been installed on the local machine. Please set the debug connection string in the project properties page.".

However I have a local SQL installation that works and worked just fine. Also nothing was changed for the database project and it doesn't have a properties page. How can this all of a sudden become a problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Do you have a database project in your solution?
If so, it is probably set to 'Build' and / or 'Deploy' in the Configuration Manager settings. Uncheck these options and the problem is solved.
Hope this helps!